# How to do addition and subtraction from different sheet and show result on another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, addition

I have three sheets **Live, Buy and Sell**, there I am maintaining Items. In Buy sheet I am tracking all buy items along with buy price & quantity similarly in sell sheet tracking sell orders. In Live sheet I want to see how many items are remaining.

Like if I purchased 200 **XYZ** item and sell 100 items so in Live sheet it should show 100 items against **XYZ**. One important point is I am adding entry in only two sheets Buy and Sell. I want Live sheet should automatically update.

In my current sheet I am using below formula for auto updating Live sheet but it has one disadvantage I can’t add multiple orders for same item. I am purchasing item in multiple order as shown in below screenshot.

`=IF(ISBLANK(Buy!C3)," ",Buy!C:C)`

**Buy Sheet –**

[image]

**Sell Sheet –**

[image]

**Live sheet Should be like this –**

[image]

I tired with some basic formulas like vlookup, if etc but that is not working.
Is there any **formula/trick** in excel to do such operations?

Below are software details -

[image]

[image]

I need answer which should be applicable for all version of excel after 2013.

Here is my sample file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFJqTYi75eiUnEqUoHP2py9x7qphGpMHZ/view?usp=sharing

Please help, thank you for your help…!

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a complete revision of my previous answer, which incorporates VikaS GuttE's comment.**

## Assumption

- You can have an additional tab
- The structure on "Buy", "Sell" and "Live" is fixed, e.g. starting with headlines in row 2.

## Changes to previous approach

- No additional columns needed on "Buy", "Sell" and "Live".
- Reduction from 12 helper columns to 3. This can be further reduced to 2 if an item cannot be listed on the sell tab without being on the buy tab as well.

## The Tabs

### The Calc tab

[image]

**Purpose**: To retrieve a list of unique items.

The highlighted areas contain the following formulas:

- "Buy" (blue): `=IF(COUNTIF(Buy!B$3:B3,Buy!B3)=1,MAX(B$2:B2)+1))`. It calculates how often the item on the same row but on the Buy tab has appeared until now. If it is the first occurance, it adds 1 to the max value so far. This way, I am getting a unique sequence for each unique item.
- "Sell" (green): `=IF(COUNTIF(buy_item,Sell!B3)>0,FALSE,IF(COUNTIF(Sell!B$3:B3,Sell!B3)=1,MAX(calc_buy)+MAX($C2:C2)+1))`. It checks, if the item on the same row but on the Sell tab already occured on the Buy tab. In that case, the result is FALSE, otherwise it checks if this is the item's first occurance on the Sell tab. In that case, it takes the current max in this column so far, adds the max of the buy column and another 1, to continue the sequence started on the buy column. This way, each item gets a unique number, regardless if it is listed on buy, on sell or on both tabs.
- "Unique" (orange): `=IF(ROW()-2>MAX(calc_sell),"",IF(ISNA(INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0))),INDEX(sell_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_sell,0)),INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0))))`. It checks if the current row minus 2 (as the formula starts in row 3) is higher than the max value of the sell column. In that case, there are no more unique items and the cell stays empty. Otherwise, it checks if the current item can be found on the Buy tab. If not, the item is taken from the Sell tab.

### The Live tab

[image]

The highlighted areas contain the following formulas:

- "Item" (purple): `=Calc!E3`. This is just a reference to the current entry on the unique items list.
- "Price" (red): `=IF(B3="","",SUMIF(buy_item,B3,buy_price)-SUMIF(sell_item,B3,sell_price))`. It checks whether there is a valid item in the same row. If yes, it sums up all buy prices for that item and subtracts all sell prices.

### The Buy tab

[image]

### The Sell tab

[image]

### Named ranges

- buy_item: =Buy!$B:$B
- buy_price: =Buy!$C:$C
- calc_buy: =Calc!$B:$B
- calc_sell: =Calc!$C:$C
- sell_item: =Sell!$B:$B
- sell_price: =Sell!$C:$C

### Formulas used

- **COUNTIF** (Excel 2003+)
- **INDEX** (Excel 2003+)
- **MATCH** (Excel 2003+)
- **MAX** (Excel 2003+)
- **ROW** (Excel 2003+)
- **SUMIF** (Excel 2003+)
- **IFNA** (Excel 2013+)

## In-depth explanation of formula

### Calc tab, column "B" with headline **Buy**, blue area: `=IF(COUNTIF(Buy!B$3:B3,Buy!B3)=1,MAX(B$2:B2)+1))`

Lets break it down:
`=IF(does_item_occur_for_first_time, next_unique_number)`

- *does_item_occur_for_first_time* = `COUNTIF(Buy!B$3:B3,Buy!B3)=1`
  `Buy!B$3:B3` this references the "Item" column on "Buy" tab. As the headline is located in row 2, I start with row 3. **Important** Please note the exact definition of the range. Only the row in the start part of the range definition (the term left of the colon) is fixed by the dollar sign in front of it. The row in the end part of the range (the part right of the colon) is not fixed. This way, the range grows with each row and it checks only the values so far.
  'Buy!B3' takes the content of cell B3 on the "Buy" tab as criteria for the "COUNTIF" formula. **Important** All four tabs need to have the same structure, meaning that the headlines should start in the same row. In addition, the two columns "Item" and "Price" need to be in the same order and column on the three tabs "Buy", "Sell" and "Live". Maybe, it helps to think of these three tabs as different z-levels in a 3D-cube. The formula above is placed in cell B3 on the "Calc" tab and thus it checks for the content of cell B3 on the "Buy" tab.

Putting these pieces of "does_item_occur_for_first_time" together, it does what it says. It checks whether the item in the same cell but on the Buy tab occurs for the first time, meaning that there is no entry above that cell that already featured that given item.

- next_unique_number = `MAX(B$2:B2)+1)`. We look at the area above (see, only the row left of the colon is fixed ($) to determine the latest number. When there is no numerical value (e.g. empty cells or headline), then it assumes 0. All we have to do is add 1 to get the next number. **Please note** that the growing range is starting in row 2 as we want to determine the number for row 3.

### Calc tab, column "C" with headline **Sell**, green area: `=IF(COUNTIF(buy_item,Sell!B3)>0,FALSE,IF(COUNTIF(Sell!B$3:B3,Sell!B3)=1,MAX(calc_buy)+MAX($C2:C2)+1))`

`=IF(did_item_occur_on_buy_tab,FALSE,IF(does_item_occur_on_sell_tab_for_the_first_time,next_unique_number_overall))`

- *did_item_occur_on_buy_tab* = `COUNTIF(buy_item,Sell!B3)>0`
  "COUNTIF" is used to determine if the current item in B3 on **Sell**(!) tab is already been listed on "Buy" tab. If that is the case, the result of this formula is "FALSE". Please note: This time we check the whole "Item" column on "Buy" tab.
- *does_item_occur_on_sell_tab_for_the_first_time* = ´COUNTIF(Sell!B$3:B3,Sell!B3)=1´
  This formula is similar to "does_item_occur_for_the_first_time" explained above. **Please note** that the column on Sell tab does not match the column of the formula's cell as the "Items" are located in column "B" which is already occupied on the "Calc" tab.
- *next_unique_number_overall* = `MAX(calc_buy)+MAX($C2:C2)+1`
  The second part (after the plus sign) is similar to "next_unique_number" explained above. The difference is the first part, as we do not want to start your sequence again with 1, but with the maximum number of the "buy" column.

### Calc tab, column "E" with headline **Unique**, orange area: `=IF(ROW()-2>MAX(calc_sell),"-",IF(ISNA(INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0))),INDEX(sell_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_sell,0)),INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0))))`

`=IF(is_there_another_unique_item,"",IF(the_item_did_not_occur_on_buy_tab,get_item_from_sell_tab,get_item_from_buy_tab))`

- *is_there_another_unique_item* = `ROW()-2>MAX(calc_sell)`. We check, whether the current row minus 2 (as the headline is located in row 2) is greater than then highest number of unique items. If that is the case, then we show nothing ("").
- *the_item_did_not_occur_on_buy_tab* = `ISNA(INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0)))`. `MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0)` looks in the "calc_buy" column for the number that equals the current row minus 2. The result is either "N/A" or the row with regard to the "calc_buy" range that features the respective item's name. Here, the term is wrapped into "ISNA" as I want to determine if the number (item's first occurance) belongs to the "buy" or "sell" tab. **Important**: all named ranges, here "buy_item" and "calc_buy" need to have the same start and end row. For the sake of convenience, I set all ranges to comprise the full column.
- *get_item_from_sell_tab* = `INDEX(sell_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_sell,0))`. The formula is the same as above without the "ISNA" wrapper. It picks the item's name from the sell tab.
- *get_item_from_buy_tab* = `INDEX(buy_item,MATCH(ROW()-2,calc_buy,0))`. The same formula is used for a third time. Here, it picks the item's name from the buy tab.

## Pitfalls and how to avoid them

- **Buy**, **Sell**, **Live** and to a certain degree **Calc** need to have the same structure. Each tab's content has to start in the same cell (here B2). If you want to add or remove columns or rows, then you should select all tabs at once and conduct that operation. *Do not forget* to ungroup the tabs after you are done to.
- Extend the formulas on **Calc** until they cover all your content on **Buy** and **Sell**, e.g. if buy features 100 rows and sell 150, then the formulas should also be included in 150 rows beneath the headline.
- All named ranges need to cover the same rows with the same start and end row. Here, all named ranges cover the whole column. If you cannot work with names, you can substitute them buy their corresponding range definition (see above).

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct approach as I can't use additional columns `Rank, Row & Iterator`

Comment: @VikaSGuttE: Thanks for your feedback. I revised my solution completely.

Comment: Can yout let me know, in which formula you are facing problems? Did you define the range names before?

Comment: The link does not work. I get the message that the file does not exist.

Comment: Might be i am doing something wrong here is my file if you want to try your own. thank you. https://tmpfiles.org/55933/sheet.xlsx

Comment: Here you go: https://tmpfiles.org/dl/55938/sheet_buyselllive.xlsx

Comment: Seems defination of `Named ranges` range in answer is wrong. Can you please check, I got the answer but i don't want to copy paste answer without understanding. I am trying to impliment answer my own and that is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233907/discussion-between-qualia-and-vikas-gutte).

Answer (score 0):

Update: You can try this new approach `={UNIQUE(Buy!A:A), {"Price";ArrayFormula((SUMIF(Buy!A2:A, UNIQUE(Buy!A2:A), Buy!B2:B))-(SUMIF(Sell!A2:A, UNIQUE(Buy!A2:A), Sell!B2:B)))}}`. I don't have Excel on my system so I can't check it in Excel. But since this one is not using `Query` it should work on Excel as well.

Previous answer:
Use this formula in `A1` of the `Live` sheet:

`=QUERY({QUERY(Buy!A1:B, "select A, B where A is not null", 1);QUERY(Sell!A2:B, "select A, -1*B where A is not null label -1*B ''", 0)}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Price'", 1)`

The assumption is that all the data (including headers) starts at `A1` in the `Buy` and `Sell` sheets.

[image]

Comment: Not working seems `Query` function is not avaialble in `Office 365`

Comment: This works in Google sheets that you've tagged in the question.

Comment: Apologize if I am not clear, but I need for both as i am doing on both platforms.

Comment: Just posted an update to the answer. See if that works.

Comment: `UNIQUE` is not avaialbe in `Office 365` .

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with one query like this:

`=arrayformula(query({Buy!A2:B;Sell!A2:A,-Sell!B2:B},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Item',sum(Col2) 'Price' ",0))`

[image]

Comment: Not working seems `Query` function is not avaialble in `Office 365`

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could find to do it is really cumbersome.  Here it is - requires Excel 2019 or 365:

In cell A2 of Live, put this formula to derive all unique Items:

```
=LET( buys, Buy!A:B,
      sales, Sell!A:B,
       bMatrix, FILTER( buys,NOT( ISBLANK( INDEX( buys, , 1 ) ) )*(INDEX( buys, , 1 )<>"Item") ),
       bItems, INDEX( bMatrix, , 1 ), rB, ROWS( bItems ),
       sMatrix, FILTER( sales,NOT( ISBLANK( INDEX( sales, , 1 ) ) )*(INDEX( sales, , 1 )<>"Item") ),
       sItems, INDEX( sMatrix, , 1 ), sB, ROWS( sItems ),
       idx, MOD( SEQUENCE( rB + sB,,0 ), rB) + 1,
       UNIQUE( IFERROR( INDEX( bItems, idx, 1 ), sItems ) )
      )
```

In cell B2 of Live put in this formula:

```
=SUMIF( Buy!A:A, A2#, Buy!B:B ) - SUMIF( Sell!A:A, A2#, Sell!B:B )
```

Result looks like this:

[image: result]

This runs really slow because it is trying to discover the arrays from columns. If you use Excel Tables instead, it speeds up.  I created tBuy and tSell and the formula in Live!A2 becomes:

```
=LET( buys, tBuy,
      sales, tSell,
       bItems, INDEX( tBuy, , 1 ), rB, ROWS( bItems ),
       sItems, INDEX( tSell, , 1 ), sB, ROWS( sItems ),
       idx, MOD( SEQUENCE( rB + sB,,0 ), rB) + 1,
       UNIQUE( IFERROR( INDEX( bItems, idx, 1 ), sItems ) )
      )
```

And in Live!B2 becomes:

```
=SUMIF( tBuy[Item], D2#, tBuy[Price] ) - SUMIF( tSell[Item], D2#, tSell[Price] )
```

Comment: Not working it saying function is not valid

Comment: Do you have Excel 365 or Excel 2019?

Comment: I have added details in question, Apologize if I confused you.

Comment: Ahh ok - mine depends on UNIQUE and no easy way to get around it - that is an Excel 2019 function.

Comment: is there any way for mine one? 

Comment: Sorry - to be clear: my answer depends on the use of UNIQUE and I don't think that's available in Excel 2016. There is a way to create a list of unique values in pre-2019 Excel but it is complex and requires a lot of helper cells.